# C# - Why impersonation is expired while ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() is performed

Tags: development, permissions, impersonation

What I’m trying to do is to connect to SharePoint list by other credentials (impersonation) and print its items.

I’m using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232154/1787061) for the impersonation, and it works almost perfectly, until **[clientContext.ExecuteQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.executequery.aspx)** is performed. I found that during this command, the impersonation is expired (actually this is the critical command I need to impersonate for).
How can I get over it?

```
CredentialsController.Impersonator imp = null;
imp = new CredentialsController.Impersonator("myUsername", "myDomain", "myPassword");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = query;
listItemCollection = selectedList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItemCollection);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // ****This line cancels the impersonation****

imp.UndoImpersonation();
```

**Notes:** 
To run the code below, you need to:

1. Add reference to two dlls (Can be downloaded [from here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8BBrEImOXRYWERqcVE0NXZnLUU&usp=sharing)):

   > Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
   >   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
2. Make sure that you use .NET 3.5 (currently not higher) 
   [image]
3. Insert real values in the following lines

   string siteUrl = "**https://SP_Server.com/sites/some_site/**";
   string listID = "**3c84e774-86c4-4b45-8a0a-437526e8728f**";
   imp = new CredentialsController.Impersonator("**myUsername**", "**myDomain**", "**myPassword**");
   Console.WriteLine(oListItem["**Title**"].ToString());

(I'm using VS2010 ultimate on Win 7 64 bit)

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace WhereAmILoggedIn
{
    class SharePointGetter
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string siteUrl = "https://SP_Server/sites/some_site/";
            string query = "<View></View>";
            string listID = "3c84e774-86c4-4b45-8a0a-437526e8728f";

            CredentialsController.Impersonator imp = null;
            imp = new CredentialsController.Impersonator("myUsername", "myDomain", "myPassword");

            ListItemCollection listItemCollection;
            try
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List selectedList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(listID));

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = query;
                listItemCollection = selectedList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(listItemCollection);

                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)); //************ Before
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)); //************ After
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Access denied", new Exception("Are you missing permissions?"));
            }


            foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItemCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oListItem["Title"].ToString());
            }

            if (imp != null)
                imp.UndoImpersonation();
        }
    }

    class CredentialsController
    {
        public enum LogonType
        {
            LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2,
            LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3,
            LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4,
            LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5,
            LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7,
            LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8, // Win2K or higher
            LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9 // Win2K or higher
        };

        public enum LogonProvider
        {
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3
        };

        public enum ImpersonationLevel
        {
            SecurityAnonymous = 0,
            SecurityIdentification = 1,
            SecurityImpersonation = 2,
            SecurityDelegation = 3
        }

        class Win32NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int LogonUser(string lpszUserName,
                 string lpszDomain,
                 string lpszPassword,
                 int dwLogonType,
                 int dwLogonProvider,
                 ref IntPtr phToken);

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
                  int impersonationLevel,
                  ref IntPtr hNewToken);

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
        }


        public class Impersonator : IDisposable
        {
            private WindowsImpersonationContext _wic;


            public Impersonator(string userName, string domainName, string password, LogonType logonType, LogonProvider logonProvider)
            {
                Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, logonType, logonProvider);
            }

            public Impersonator(string userName, string domainName, string password)
            {
                Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT);
            }

            public Impersonator()
            { }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                UndoImpersonation();
            }

            public void Impersonate(string userName, string domainName, string password)
            {
                Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT);
            }

            public void Impersonate(string userName, string domainName, string password, LogonType logonType, LogonProvider logonProvider)
            {
                UndoImpersonation();

                IntPtr logonToken = IntPtr.Zero;
                IntPtr logonTokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
                try
                {
                    // revert to the application pool identity, saving the identity of the current requestor
                    _wic = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero);

                    // do logon & impersonate
                    if (Win32NativeMethods.LogonUser(userName,
                        domainName,
                        password,
                        (int)logonType,
                        (int)logonProvider,
                        ref logonToken) != 0)
                    {
                        if (Win32NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(logonToken, (int)ImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation, ref logonTokenDuplicate) != 0)
                        {
                            var wi = new WindowsIdentity(logonTokenDuplicate);
                            wi.Impersonate(); // discard the returned identity context (which is the context of the application pool)
                        }
                        else
                            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                    else
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (logonToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                        Win32NativeMethods.CloseHandle(logonToken);

                    if (logonTokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                        Win32NativeMethods.CloseHandle(logonTokenDuplicate);
                }
            }

            /// Stops impersonation.
            public void UndoImpersonation()
            {
                // restore saved requestor identity
                if (_wic != null)
                    _wic.Undo();
                _wic = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run the program with the credentials of the user you are trying to impersonate?

Comment: @W0ut, In this case, there is no really impersonation, the credentials before and after the impersonation are the same, thus everything is going fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is this code running on the SharePoint server? If so try using the default SharePoint API and the runwithelevatedpriviledges rather than an impersonator and clientcontext.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx

Comment: No, this code is running on every client PC without SharePoint server installed.